# Getting stocks by industry via Yahoo Finance

Tags: web-services, finance, yahoo-finance

i want to list all available industries ( like: http://biz.yahoo.com/p/ ) and show all corresponding stocks.
Until now I'm using YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback for the symbol suggestion and http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=... for getting the stock's data.

Does anyone have any idea how to get all industries and corresponding stocks?
Is there another hidden Yahoo API?

Answer (score 20):

Lists of all available industries are called [**`GICS Sectors`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard) for Standard and Poor's (S&P500 will use that) and [**`ICB`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Classification_Benchmark) for Dow Jones and FTSE. Hence it used by Nasdaq, Nyse and others markets.
It seems like Yahoo uses a third industry classification by Morning Star, but since I'm not quite sure I will give both ways of retrieving data.

### Morning Star

I don't know if Yahoo really sticks to this classification, but some names were really close so let's see it:
You need to go to their [Index Data](http://corporate.morningstar.com/us/asp/detail.aspx?filter=Equity&page=DailyTrailingReturns.xml&xmlfile=613.xml) and in each sector, click on it and then at the bottom ***View complete index holdings***.
It's not as precise as in Yahoo industry list, but it's all you can do with Morning Star. Not very convincing, I know...

### GICS Sectors

**`GICS Sectors`** are now a trademark of Standard and Poor's and then data have to be sought for in S&P's website.
**Short answer:** take a look at this [page](http://www.standardandpoors.com/indices/sp-500/en/us/%3FindexId=spusa-500-usduf--p-us-l--?ffFix=yes), you will need to be registered (it's free and easy) and you can download spreadsheets (xls) with stocks and corresponding sectors. **Nevertheless**, things aren't always easy, and you will have to do a bit of a search to retrieve all stocks with their corresponding industries.   For example, the file **INDICATED_RATE_CHANGE.xls** will give you some companies and their sectors in each month of 2012. Using that and **SP500_DividendAristocrats_2012.xls** you should be able to retrieve at least a large part of S&P 500 companies.

### ICB

<strike>**`ICB`** is used by NYSE, NASDAQ etc... Then it's a lot simpler than S&P and MorningStar. [Here is your answer](http://www.nyse.com/indexes/nyaindex.csv). **BOOM!** Direct link!</strike>
 Link is dead :(

### Finally

I strongly advise you to use the simpler and most-used industry classification index: the **`ICB`**. It will always be available and publicly displayed since millions of investors relay everyday on it, **without** having to use S&P financial services or MorningStar brokerage services...

## EDIT

You can look at nasdaq.com to retrieve all companies and their corresponding sector: [here for Nasdaq](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download) and [here for Nyse](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download)

Answer (score 1):

Get all industry-IDs from here:
http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html
(look at the links)

Then use YQL ( https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ )

with a query like this:
**select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id=912**